# How to loop through an Factory in Laravel multiple times...?

Tags: laravel, factories

How to loop through a Factory in Laravel multiple times...?

// FileFactory

```
$factory->define(File::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $imageNumber = 0;
    $imageNumber++;
    $productId = 1;
    return [
        'file_refer_type' => 1,
        'file_refer_id' => $productId,
        'name' => 'Product Name ' . $productId,
        'title' => 'Product Title ' . $productId,
        'image_type' => 1,
        'rank' => $imageNumber,
        'file_type' => 1,
        'file_size' => null,
        'file_url' => config('app.url') . 'images/products/' . $productId . '_' . $imageNumber . '.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => config('app.url') .'images/products/' . $productId . '_' . $imageNumber . '-thumb.jpg',
        'file_name' => null,
        'container' => null,
        'folder' => null,
        'file_extension' => null,
        'file_width' => null,
        'file_length' => null,
    ];
});
```

//FileTableSeeder

```
public function run()
{
    factory('App\File', 7)->create();
}
```

What if I wanted to create a loop for 2 products...? 
This loop only loops for 1 product 7 times...

It would be possible to update the seeder like so... However, this is quite repetitive...
What can I do to reuse the loop...

**EDIT:**
// Expected results image...

- 1st product has 7 images
- 2nd product has 2 images

[image: Expected results]

Comment: Just to be clear, your factory create 7 files your logic for counting products is flawed. What is the correlation between productId and number?

Comment: @mrhn please see updated answer...

Comment: shouldnt product be a relationship since this is a file model?

Comment: @mrhn not required a relationship in the factory as this is just for testing...

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
$factory->define(File::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $imageNumber = 0;

    $imageNumber++;
    $productId = 1;

    $products = [
        [
        'file_refer_type' => 1,
        'file_refer_id' => $productId,
        'name' => 'Product Name ' . $productId,
        'title' => 'Product Title ' . $productId,
        'image_type' => 1,
        'rank' => $imageNumber,
        'file_type' => 1,
        'file_size' => null,
        'file_url' => config('app.url') . 'images/products/' . $productId . '_' . $imageNumber . '.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => config('app.url') .'images/products/' . $productId . '_' . $imageNumber . '-thumb.jpg',
        'file_name' => null,
        'container' => null,
        'folder' => null,
        'file_extension' => null,
        'file_width' => null,
        'file_length' => null,
        ],
        [
        'file_refer_type' => 2,
        'file_refer_id' => $productId,
        'name' => 'Product Name ' . $productId,
        'title' => 'Product Title ' . $productId,
        'image_type' => 2,
        'rank' => $imageNumber,
        'file_type' => 2,
        'file_size' => null,
        'file_url' => config('app.url') . 'images/products/' . $productId . '_' . $imageNumber . '.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => config('app.url') .'images/products/' . $productId . '_' . $imageNumber . '-thumb.jpg',
        'file_name' => null,
        'container' => null,
        'folder' => null,
        'file_extension' => null,
        'file_width' => null,
        'file_length' => null,
        ]
    ];


    return $products[$imageNumber%2];
});
```

Comment: It should generate 7 files for 1st product.. 2 files for 2nd product...